# Table Row is not filling the full width of the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm creating a HTML form and having an issue with getting the 2 column rows to fill the full width of the table. I have tried using colspace and setting a width to it but it's not working. I have also tried setting the  width to 100% but it's also not working. CSS also doesn't seem to be making any changes to the

```css
body {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 25px;
}

.table-heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #8080802e;
}

.demographics {
  text-align: left;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-heading" colspan="3">APPLICANT'S INFORMATION</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name:</td>
      <td>First Name:</td>
      <td>Middle Intial:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Current Address:</td>
      <td>City:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>State:</td>
      <td>Zip Code:</td>
      <td>Phone #:</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Spouse's Name:</td>
      <td>Phone #:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-heading" colspan="3">CHILDREN'S INFORMATION (NO STEP CHILDREN)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1)</td>
      <td>5)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2)</td>
      <td>6)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3)</td>
      <td>7)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4)</td>
      <td>8)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have rows with 1, 2, and 3 columns, you need to use `colspan` with a number that is divisible by all three numbers, in this case, 6.

- For one column per row, you would use `colspan="6"` because 6/6 = 1
- For two columns per row, `colspan="3"` because 6/3 = 2
- For three columns per row, `colspan="2"` because 6/2=2

Here is the HTML for a table with 1, 2, and 3 columns:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">One Column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Two Column</td>
    <td colspan="3">Two Column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Three Column</td>
    <td colspan="2">Three Column</td>
    <td colspan="2">Three Column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Two Separate Table.

```css
body {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 25px;
}

.table-heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #8080802e;
}

.demographics {
  text-align: left;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 6px;
}
.no-border-top{
  border-top : 0
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-heading" colspan="3">APPLICANT'S INFORMATION</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name:</td>
      <td>First Name:</td>
      <td>Middle Intial:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Current Address:</td>
      <td>City:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>State:</td>
      <td>Zip Code:</td>
      <td>Phone #:</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Spouse's Name:</td>
      <td>Phone #:</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="no-border-top">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-heading no-border-top" colspan="2">CHILDREN'S INFORMATION (NO STEP CHILDREN)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1)</td>
      <td>5)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2)</td>
      <td>6)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3)</td>
      <td>7)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4)</td>
      <td>8)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```